# how to deal with this error in c parameter names (without types) in function declaration?

Tags: c, pointers

i am using this as a pointer to a function that accepts a Node which is a struct and returns bool type but i get this error :

```
parameter names (without types) in function declaration
```

the stuct is like this :

```
struct node_t
{
    Element data;
    Node next;
};

typedef struct node_t* Node;

typedef void* Element;

typedef Element (*copy_function) (Element);


Node concatLists( Node head1, Node head2, condition_function ConditionF ,copy_function CopyFunction)
{
    Node head = NULL;
    Node *current = &head;

    for ( ; head1 != NULL; head1 = head1->next )
    {
        if ( ConditionF( head1 ) )
        {
            *current = malloc( sizeof(Node ) );
            ( *current )->data = CopyFunction(head1->data);
            ( *current )->next = NULL;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }

    for ( ; head2 != NULL; head2 = head2->next )
    {
        if ( ConditionF( head2 ) )
        {
            *current = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
            ( *current )->data = CopyFunction(head2->data);
            ( *current )->next = NULL;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }

    return head;
}




void insert( Node *head, void* a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        Node tmp = malloc( sizeof( Node) );
        tmp->data = a[i];
        tmp->next = *head;
        *head = tmp;
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }
}


int main( void )
{
    Node head1 = NULL;
    Node head2 = NULL;
    int a1[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int a2[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    const size_t N1 = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 ); 
    const size_t N2 = sizeof( a2 ) / sizeof( *a2 );

    insert( &head1,(*(int *) a1), N1 );//// i get error here
    insert( &head2,(*(int *) a2), N2 );

    Node head3 = concatLists( head1, head2,&odd ,&copyInt);
    Node head4 = concatLists( head1, head2, &IsPrime ,&copyInt);
return 0;
}
```

the code above takes two nodes and connect them with each other on a specific condition ..

> UPDATE:

i get this error in the line  `insert( &head1,(*(int *) a1), N1 );`:

> passing argument 2 of 'insert' makes pointer from integer without a
>   cast [-Wint-conversion]

ANOTHR UPDATE :
// a function that finds if the data is odd

```
static bool odd( Node n )
{
    int* x=NULL;
     *x=(*(int *)getNodeData(n))%2; // error here 
    return true;
}
```

what could be the problem that i get this warning ?

Comment: show your code?

Comment: ok i am gonna show it even thogh i don't get warning on the code ..

Comment: AFAIK, `Element (*copy_function)(Element)` is allowed in C++ only. In C, you have to provide names for the formal parameters (even if the names are never used otherwise): Please try this: `Element (*copy_function)(Element e)`.

Comment: omg yes ! but i still get this error : unknown type name 'Node'  even though i have typedef struct node_t* Node; in the function :\

Comment: @lia *the minimal exact code* and the error and *which line* the error happens on.

Comment: no i think it is not just for c++ i just searched it

Comment: C code is single pass - you must have the typedef *before* the definition of `struct node_t`

Comment: You use `Node` in `struct node_t` before you typedef it.

Comment: @Scheff well, and that's wrong. It is possible in C, but it is possible to have parameters without types in archaic C which is what this error points to...

Comment: @lia I agree, couldn't prove it in gcc (neither c89, c99, c11).

Comment: I guess, the problem is that `condition_function` is used this is not declared.

Comment: ok so now i get an error on my main function which i didn't insert here or this will question will be super long

Comment: i get error in this function in main :  const size_t N1 = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 ); i get this error: passing argument 2 of 'insert' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, I confused it with anonymous function arguments: For `int main(int, char**) { return 0; }` I get `error: parameter name omitted`.

Comment: Please, try this instead: `enum { N1 = sizeof a1 / sizeof *a1 };`

Comment: i wrote this code on eclipse so i have a header file and a c and a main file so it is confusing :\

Comment: @lia I did `cat >test.c <<EOF` instead. Thus, no IDE issues... ;-)

Comment: `void* a[]` -> `int *a`

Comment: but the insert function accept void * :\

Comment: Then `void *a` and cast to `int` within `insert`, and just pass `a1` and `a2`

Comment: Are you aware that `void *a[]` is the same as `void **a` (pointer to pointer to void)?

Comment: but the whole point is it work with void * so i could use this function not only for int type

Comment: lol yes why asking ! what stupid thing did i do ?

Comment: You are also aware that you can pass `whatever**` as `void *` and handle the cast to and from the actual type as needed.

Comment: ok now i fixed the code but it just stopeed to work suddenly lol i am gonna debbug it and see what the problem now

Comment: OK, I realized what `void *a[]` is intended for. This is OK. But you may not pass `a1` in `main()`. This is not an array of pointers (not at all). At best, you could provide `&a1` and **1** (for `n`).

Comment: so you suggest i use instead of :insert( &head1,(*(int *) a1), N1 );

Comment: insert( &head1,&a1, N1 ); ??

Comment: The only way it would work: `insert(&head1, &a1, 1);` `a1` is an array of `int`. `insert()` expects an array of pointers to pointers (to `void` but the `void` isn't the problem here).

Comment: it is not working !! if i do this a get this error : passing argument 2 of 'insert' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]  /// this is just frustrating

Comment: You could also do this: `int *pA1[] = { a1 + 0, a1 + 1, a1 + 2 };` `insert(&head1, pA1, N1);`

Comment: also i ned the N it gives me the size of the array ..

Comment: didn't work either ! ok i gave up actually

Comment: Incompatible pointer types might be cause by trying to pass `int**` to `void**`. Not that I recommend this in general, but a cast `(void**)` would make the compiler silent...

Comment: Don't give up. Fight this through and you will start to understand how "C works". Things like yours are actually the one which make C a difficult language (though it has only 40 keywords)...

Comment: yeah the compiler did shut lol but also i still can't get this annoying code to work

Comment: And, don't  forget to check in the debugger "what really happens". To get it compiled is the 1st task, to make it running stable the 2nd...

Comment: why is this wrong ? int* x=NULL;
  *x=(*(int *)getNodeData(n))%2;

Comment: ok i don't want to give up , but when you are still awake 8:00 am from last night you start thinking about giveing up lol but thanks a lot you helped me lots

Comment: You try to dereference NULL.

Comment: Go to sleep (hopefully not to work). Then come back. You will find more comments or answers and (maybe other) people helping you then.

Comment: yes yes but if i remove * it won't work

Comment: Describe in prose what that line is meant to achieve.

Comment: will i am not sleaping because i nedd this done by tomorrow

Comment: oh lol it is actually today because it is already morning !!

Comment: You might want to malloc some space for x, instead of writing something via NULL.

Comment: it is a function actually that checks whther the data in the node is odd or not

Comment: Here is prose for `*x=(*(int *)getNodeData(n))%2;`: Write the following via NULL. Call getNodeData(n), interpret the return value as pointer to int. get the int it points to. Calculate the 2-modulo of that.   Now you write the prose for what it SHOULD do.

Comment: What you might want is `int IntegerLikeBoolean; IntegerLikeBoolean=getNodeData(n)%2;` Write something to a simple integer/boolean variable. Call getNodeData(n). Take the 2-modulo of that.

Comment: ok i will actually rewrite my code again i have another idea now

Comment: You might want to read this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The code you put cannot reproduce the exact error you have explained. There are many errors in the code. And that is why others are not able to help you much. Please put the exact code which when you compile will give the same error for everyone.

Comment: This question is a mess. There's an error message, code that contains a different error, then a third error message (from nonsensical code), and finally a fourth unspecified error and an incomplete code fragment. Please figure out what exactly you're asking and post a [mcve].

Comment: Are you still awake? I just made an update of my answer.

Comment: oh no i fall asleep i couldn't be awake any longer lol but yeah i just changed it a bit and sumbet it .. just saw you'r answer oh i wish i still have time to submit but unfortinatlly not :( ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide some help, this is what I got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node_t {
  void *data;
  struct node_t *next;
};
typedef struct node_t *Node;

typedef void(*print_function)(void*);

typedef void* (*copy_function)(void*);

typedef int (*condition_function)(void*);

void printList(Node head, const char *label, print_function printFunc)
{
  printf("%s", label);
  for (; head != NULL; head = head->next) {
    printf(" -> "); (*printFunc)(head->data);
  }
  printf(" -> -|\n");
}

void insert1(Node *head, void *a)
{
  Node *current = head;
  // find tail pointer (i.e. the end of list)
  while (*current != NULL) {
    current = &(*current)->next;
  }
  // make node node
  *current = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  (*current)->data = a; // Attention! This is a flat copy.
  (*current)->next = NULL;
}

void insert(Node *head, void *a[], size_t n)
{
  Node *current = head;
  // find tail pointer (i.e. the end of list)
  while (*current != NULL) {
    current = &(*current)->next;
  }
  // insert nodes
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    *current = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*current)->data = a[i]; // Attention! This is a flat copy.
    (*current)->next = NULL;
    current = &(*current)->next;
  }
}

Node concatLists(
  Node head1, Node head2, condition_function condFunc, copy_function copyFunc)
{
  Node head = NULL;
  Node *current = &head;
  for (; head1 != NULL; head1 = head1->next) {
    if (condFunc(head1->data)) {
      *current = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      (*current)->data = copyFunc(head1->data);
      (*current)->next = NULL;
      current = &(*current)->next;
    }
  }
  for (; head2 != NULL; head2 = head2->next) {
    if (condFunc(head2->data)) {
      *current = malloc(sizeof(Node));
      (*current)->data = copyFunc(head2->data);
      (*current)->next = NULL;
      current = &(*current)->next;
    }
  }
  return head;
}

void printInt(void *data) { printf("%d", *(int*)data); }

void* copyInt(void *data)
{
  int *newData = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *newData = *(int*)data;
  return newData;
}

int isOdd(void *data)
{
#if 0 /* my style: */
  return *(int*)data & 1;
#else /* like in OP: */
  return *(int*)data % 2;
#endif /* 0 */
}

int main()
{
  Node head1 = NULL, head2 = NULL;
  int a1[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  int a2[] = { 4, 5, 6 };
  insert1(&head1, a1);
  insert1(&head1, a1 + 1);
  insert1(&head1, &a1[2]);
  printList(head1, "head1", &printInt);
  { void *pA2[] = { a2, a2 + 1, &a2[2] };
    enum { N2 = sizeof pA2 / sizeof *pA2 };
    insert(&head2, pA2, N2);
  }
  printList(head2, "head2", &printInt);
  Node head3 = concatLists(head1, head2, &isOdd, &copyInt);
  printList(head3, "head3", &printInt);
  return 0;
}
```

Notes:

1. To make debugging simpler, I derived `insert1()` from `insert()`. Once, I got the first running and was easy to apply the fixes to the second.
2. I added a "traversal" to find the end of list for each insertion. (This was missing in the OP and might or might not be intended.)
3. I added `printList()` function. This makes it much easier for me when I can "something see".
4. In function `concatLists()`, I changed the calls of `condFunc()`. (Unfortunately, the type definition of `condition_function` is missing in the OP. Thus, I did it in the "same style" like `print_function` and `copy_function`.)
5. As function `concatLists()` makes deep copies of the nodes (i.e. it copies the data of nodes as well), I wonder why `insert()` does make flat copies instead (i.e. copies the data *pointers* of nodes). For me, it would look "cleaner" to use deep copy in general, but that's a matter of taste.
6. IMHO, it's bad style to "hide" pointers in `typedef`s. As pointers are a common source of any kind of errors, I think it's good to "see" them always.
   Therefore, *I* had defined type `Node`: `typedef struct node_t Node;`, and had used it always with `*` or `**` to make indirections explicitly. (Actually, I did it this way first but changed it before posting the code to make it like it was done in the OP.)

Tested with gcc in cygwin:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -o test-list test-list.c

$ ./test-list
head1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> -|
head2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> -|
head3 -> 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> -|

$
```

Comment: hi :) so whenever i accept your answer for some reason they undo it :\ also i asked if i can submit again and they alowed me to , so i used what you wrote for me and added some things :}

Comment: I just wondered about my rep. counter "yoyo-ing". These are good news about the option for subsequent submission. I wouldn't say "I wrote this for you". Actually, I took your sample code, adjusted it for debug, removed some bugs, added some things I found useful. Thereby, I simply tried to do it the way you did it at the pieces of code which were already in good manner. I probably had provided my own sample (or sent another dozens of comments) to let you do the work alone if you hadn't mentioned the close deadline and the sleepless night. (something I know really well concerning my own past)

Comment: yeah yeah ofcourse i know you didn't write this for me but i wanted to thank you for your help thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to produce the exact error, but here is my guess:

```
insert( &head1,(*(int *) a1), N1 );
```

In this line and in the next one that follows.

The second argument is of the form: `(*(int *) a1)`

Let me explain it for you:

`a1` is of type `int *`

`*` (de-referencing operator)  and `(int *)` (type casting operator) have same precedence. And are right to left associative.

Hence this is what will happen:

1. `a` will be type-casted to `int *` (which it already is)
2. then `*a` will be performed (value at address a). Which returns an `int` i.e. `a[0]`
3. But the function expects a pointer, not an int. Hence it will throw error.

NOTE: Your code has many errors, which makes it difficult to verify the correctness of my answer. Please provide the exact code which when compiled on any C compiler (or at least `gcc`) will produce the same error that you are explaining.